# Why doesn't R change my working directory?

Tags: r

I am currently working on extending my knowledge on text mining. I am trying to import a file to work  on using  `readLines`  and R studio produces an error of the form :
`Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection` . I know this means it cannot find the file so I try to change the working directory so it will but I can't seem to do that. Writing the code :
`setwd("~/text 2/semi structured text mining")`
it gives me:
`Error in setwd("~/text 2/semi structured text mining") :  cannot change working directory` and when i try to do it from  Session  it doesn't produce an error but when i ask the working directory with `getwd()` it gives me the old working directory. Why doesn't R let me change the working directory? Any help would be much appreciated as I am stack at this point for days. Thank you

Comment: It is hard to say without more information. This could be a problem involving a slight misspelling or a peculiarity of your operating system. Try `readLines(file.choose())` to see if you can navigate through the folders to the file and select it. The File tab on R Studio also lets you navigate to a directory and then make it the working directory without using the `setwd()` function.

Comment: I don't believe R understands the "~" in the directory path.  I usually take the output from `getwd()`, edit the results and then paste it into `setwd()`

Comment: Thank you very much. It was actually that R didn't understand the "~" in the directory path.